# Flutter: setState not working in callback of ValueNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget displaying pictures I shoot from the camera.
I am using a `ValueNotifier` called `notifierpicture` with a default value of 0.
When I shoot the picture it goes to 1, after some processing to 2 and later to 0 again.

```
class PictureViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  PictureViewer({Key? key, required this.DA}) : super(key: key);
  String DA;
  @override
  State<PictureViewer> createState() => _PictureViewerState();
}

class _PictureViewerState extends State<PictureViewer> {
  int counterforloadingscreens = 0;

  void addNotifier(){
    globals.notifierpicture.addListener(doTaskWhenNotified);
  }

  void doTaskWhenNotified() {
    setState((){
      if (globals.notifierpicture.value == 1){
        counterforloadingscreens = 1;
      } else {
        counterforloadingscreens = 0;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    addNotifier();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Listview.builder(...)
```

The problem is, wenn the valuenotifier changes value, it will run the code in `void doTaskWhenNotified()` (tried with a simple print), but setState do not update the widget.

What is wrong here? - I don`t get the clue when setState() will work and when it will not work.. - I mean I am calling setState in a Stateful widget..

Thanks..

Comment: Add a print statement to your build() method. If doTaskWhenNotified() is called, then setState() is also called. The problem is somewhere else. BTW, it's a good idea to check if a widget is still mounted before calling setState().

Comment: @AndreiVolgin: I have added a print in build methode - after set state, this print is printed - but the widget will not update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on when your notifier fires, your widget might not be read to be rebuilt. In such a case, you could try to schedule the `setState` via

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {...}));
```

But apart from that - If you already have a `ValueProvider`, you could get rid of manually adding listeners and scheduling rebuilds by using a [`ValueListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html).

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
        valueListenable: <your-int-value-notifier>
        builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget? child) {
            return Listview.builder(...);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: due to @Andrei Volgin I added a print in build-method - after `setState` this print got printed, but the widget wont update.
I have tried it with `ValueListenableBuilder` but also widget wont update

Comment: It looks like the problem is not in setState. The problem is in the widget itself.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin: thanks, there was also a problem with the variable that the rebuild dont change anything